# make 12.04 look like 10.04, please!

Tags: 12.04, 10.04, panel

I don't like the 12.04 panel. Is there a simple way to make it look like 10.04 which was perfect in its design?

I installed gnome-panel and followed the instructions but nothing happened.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 11.04 and higher no longer use Gnome2, they use Unity which is a fork of Gnome3. Unity cannot be made to look the same as Gnome2. There are few options for Gnome2 fans, and this whole pissed a lot of people off, but that's old news. You can stick with 10.04 thus enjoying the environment you like but being unable to run newer software, you can suck it up and use Unity (perhaps it will grow on you, lolz. Loads of people have given in and accepted their fate), you can try a different desktop environment like xfce, kde, lxde, or you can install a different desktop environment that is more Gnome2-like such as a Gnome2 fork called Mate Desktop.

**How To Install Mate Desktop On Ubuntu 12.04:**

In Terminal Type:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://packages.mate-desktop.org/repo/ubuntu precise main"
```

In Terminal Type:

```
"sudo apt-get update"

"sudo apt-get install mate-archive-keyring"

"sudo apt-get update"

"sudo apt-get install mate-core"

"sudo apt-get install mate-desktop-environment"
```

**How To Install XFCE On Ubuntu 12.04:**

In terminal type:

```
"sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop"
```

**How To Install LXDE On Ubuntu 12.04:**

In terminal type:

```
"sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop"
```

**How To Install KDE On Ubuntu 12.04:**

In terminal type:

```
"sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop"
```

And if none of these meet your liking there are other desktop environments out there like EDE, Cinnamon, and so on.

Comment: you still can use `gnome-session-fallback`

Answer (score 1):

You can install the old desktop `sudo apt-get install gnome-session-fallback`

This will install you the old one.

Now logout and login using the new Desktop by clicking on the ubuntu logo in the lightdm login page(the place you write your username and password) and choose the session gnome-session-fallback